MediaRecorder (JS) not working on webkit web browsers when deployed, locally and on Chromium it is working fine either way
I have a flask app that is deployed using Caddy and Gunicorn. I use the MediaRecorder JS libary to record the microphone of a user and afterwards send it to GPT. This works awesome on Chromium and Webkit browsers when I have a local server on my computer. But when I deploy the project to my VPS using Caddy and Gunicorn it does not work as supposed on only webkit browsers. Sometimes it detects the first word and other times it detects nothing. I will attach my JS code that uses MediaRecorder and some pictures when run locally and when I run it using my VPS.
Here is the JS code

recordButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    if (!isRecording) {
        isRecording = true;
        recordButton.innerText = 'Stoppa inspelning';
        await startRecording();
    } else {
        isRecording = false;
        recordButton.innerText = 'Starta inspelning';
        await stopRecording();
    }
});

async function startRecording() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });
    mediaRecorder.start();
    statusElement.textContent = 'Spelar just nu in...';
}


function stopRecording() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', async () => {
            statusElement.textContent = 'Inspelning avslutad.';
            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
            audioChunks = [];
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('audio', audioBlob);

            fetch('/update_button', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    buttonValue: button_value,
                }),
            });

            console.log('Button value:', button_value);

            const response = await fetch('/transcribe', {
                method: 'POST',
                body:
                    formData,
            });
            const { transcription, answer } = await response.json();

            responseElement.textContent = 'User input: ' + transcription;
            answerElement.textContent = 'GPT answer: ' + answer;


            resolve();
        });


        mediaRecorder.stop();
    });
}

Here is a picture of a correct output when I run the project locally (using webkit browser - I always use the same input)

Here is a picture of a faulty output when the project is deployed via my VPS (using webkit browser - I always use the same input)

I want to add that I do not get any errors on the server side or client side.
I have tried restarting the VPS, I have tried updated all my python libraries, I have tried different devices (mobile and desktop). All I found was that the project does not work on webkit browser but only when deployed. Locally everything works fine.
Solution
How to convert AAC/MP4A to MP3 using FFMPEG in full length? Audio file gets cut off after 1 second
